# What is the difference between requireActivity and onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

In my code I was inconveniently loading pictures after `onCreateView()` because I was not sure if the activity was available yet. Because Glide required an activity context I placed the section of code into `onActivityCreated()`:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    //Crash unexpected since onActivityCreated should always have activity available
    Glide.with(activity!!)
        .load(viewModel.moment!!.mediaPath)
        .into(binding.momentPhoto);
}
```

However, after looking through some best practices on Github many examples load the photos in `onCreateView()`. They do this by using the `requireActivity()` method:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_photo_editor, container, false)

    Glide.with(requireActivity())
          .load(viewModel.moment!!.mediaPath)
          .into(binding.momentPhoto);

    return binding.root
}
```

Does anyone know what the difference between using an activity reference after `onActivityCreated()` and getting the activity reference from `requireActivity()`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We should split this answer in two parts.

**1. The difference between `activity!!` and `requireActivity()`**

They both invoke `getActivity()` and they both throw an exception if the `Activity` is null. The only difference is the type of the returned exception and its message. Certainly, `requireActivity()` throws a more explicit exception.

**2. The "difference" between `onActivityCreated()` and `onCreateView()`**

The method `onActivityCreated()` is invoked **after** `onCreateView()` when both the `Activity` and the `Fragment` view are **already** created.

The method `onCreateView()` is invoked **before** `onActivityCreated()` when the `Fragment` view should be **still** created.

In your scenario, there's no difference in where you put your `Glide` usage. It would have been a difference if your `Fragment` retains its instance or in the case the `ImageView` is inside the `Activity`.

By the way, I would move your `Glide` usage in `onViewCreated()` since `onActivityCreated()` is going to be deprecated soon (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02).

Comment: Thanks so much, this clarified everything ! :)

Comment: @ChristopherDottellis No problem!

Comment: onCreateView() can definitely run without the activity (activity == null).  It is not safe to assume you have the activity when onCreateView() is called.  It's bitten me personally in the past.

Answer (score 19):

They are totally different things and there is not a single similarity except word activity in them.

`getActivity()` (or `activity` in case of Kotlin) is the method to access the activity that created the current fragment. It can be null so you need to check for nullability inside your code.

`requireActivity()` a method that returns the non-null activity instance to fragment or throws an exception.

If you are **100%** sure that in your fragment's lifecycle, activity is not null, use `requireActivity()` as it needs no !! notation inside code, otherwise put it inside try-catch block to avoid *NullPointerException*.

`onActivityCreated()` is a lifecycle method that is called when a fragment's parent activity has been created.

.

Comment: When fragment is detached from activity and some non ui callback is triggered you will get activity null

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good but I think it's a little mistake A correction here getActivity() does not throw any exception. It just returns null.
I have covered it in detail [here](https://medium.com/@faisaldeveloper493/difference-between-getactivity-and-requireactivity-80932efd9fb4).

1. The only difference is requireActivity throw an
   **IllegalStateException** if the Activity is null. but getActivity
   return null when that Fragment is not attached to the Activity.
   requireActivity() returned exception and its message. Certainly,
   requireActivity() throws a more explicit exception.