# get parent activity by a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-api-30

I'm currently having two activities, MainActivity and ResultActivity and both of them will use the same fragment - Favorite.
my question is:
How to know which activity is containing the fragment? For example I have a fragment A inside activity ResultActivity, and how can I know if fragment A is contained in ResultActivity or MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

You can check an instance of this activity.

**getActivity()** - can return **null** value, so you need check this.

**Java**

```
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
//          TODO
        } else if (getActivity() !=null && getActivity() instanceof ResultActivity) {
//            TODO
        }
```

**Kotlin**

```
        if (activity !=null && activity is MainActivity) {
//          TODO
        } else if (activity !=null && activity is ResultActivity) {
//            TODO
        }
```

*Edited*: you can also use another method **requireActivity** the difference is that you receive notNull value, but if activity null you can get **IllegalStateException**.

**requireActivity()** - return **notNull** value but can throw Exception.

```
      try {
        if (requireActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
            //          TODO
        } else if (requireActivity) instanceof ResultActivity) {
            //            TODO
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
```

**Kotlin**

```
        try {
        if (requireActivity() is MainActivity) {
            //          TODO
        } else if (requireActivity) is ResultActivity) {
            //            TODO
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: thank u so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best practice for you.

And to get Activity you should use requireActivity()

And to get Context you should use requireContext()

```
// for kotlin
fun isMainActivity(): Boolean {
    return requireActivity() is MainActivity
}

public boolean isMainActivity() {
    return requireActivity() instanceof MainActivity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, may I ask the difference between requireActivity() and getActivity()? I can’t find a proper answer for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61045701/5429327

Comment: this answer is also correct, the only difference is where the error will be inside method requireActivity or your implementation when you try to check Null value) But I have updated the answer.